# Magento: Which is the controller for address changes in admin area?

Tags: magento

Which is the controller that is used when an address is changed from the order view in the admin area? I thought it was Addresscontroller.php, but it isnt.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely, there is a request url which updates address when you save address from sales order grid :

> youradminhandle/sales_order/addressSave/address_id/123/key/3werg01875bfbe163fee7c8e2c4ade0a3547

here the controller will be inside

> app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\OrderController.php

where you need to check

> addressSaveAction()